# MediaFoundation - Frame is ready?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I am using Media Foundation to play a video, which I need to edit in real time, so I need to know when a frame is ready to be presented, but the callback does not offer such a message.

My only idea is checking the frame rate, then setting a timer to just shy of that and using GetPosition to check where I am against where I was the last time the timer was called, but there must be a better way than this.

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you inject your own [IMFStreamSink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms705657(v=vs.85).aspx) instance in the topologoy, do the editing in your implementation of `IMFStreamSink::ProcessSample` and passing the edited to whatever output node you are using currently?

Also, if you are using EVR, you could make a custom presenter - see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530107(v=vs.85).aspx#repaintingframes) article on MSDN.

Comment: After spending the day on this, I can safely say, I am entirely confused. I am totally new to MediaFoundation, and to get it working I used the tutorial on the MSDN site below. I am not sure how to integrate an IMFStreamSink into the program. It seems like it is its own way of doing things, so I would need to scrap this and start over. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728866(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution. Set the playback speed on the session, then create a presentation clock from the session. Set a timer, and check the presentation clock. When time has passed equal to the playback speed for one tick, a new frame is being presented.